# URLs with slash in the middle of parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I am creating a MVC 4 application and using the route mapping to route a url like
http://ModelSearch.com/Home/PartDetail/1000-1583-XIR/a

```
routes.MapRoute("PartDetail", "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{rev}", new { action = "PartDetail" });
```

There might be id like "1000/1584"
http://ModelSearch.com/Home/PartDetail/**1000/1584**/b

How do I handle it from new mapRoute? wildcard doesn't work for middle parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can re arrange your parameter and use the wildcard url segments for Id at the end of your url pattern.

```
[Route("Home/PartDetail/{rev}/{*id}")]
public ActionResult PartDetail(string rev,string id)
{
    return Content("rev:"+rev+",id:"+id);
}
```

The `*id` is like a catch anything. So `"1000/1584"` segment of the request url will be mapped to the `id` parameter.

Comment: To get the behavior you are after (having an id value with `\` in it) ,you need to keep that as the last param